# Not loading the window from the MainMenu.xib, instead load another window

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

This is my first Mac OS-X app, so this might be a stupid question.
In my app basically i have two windows,

1. The Main window which comes with ***MainMenu.xib*** file by default
2. I created another ***WindowController*** with another xib file.

I have created a AppController class which is connected to the MainMenu.xib, what i am trying to do in the `awakeFromNib` method in the AppController class is load either the main Window or the custom window, but load the Main Menu each time. Is it possible?

I couldn't do it the previous way, if i needed to use the custom window, i would first create the main window and close it immediately.
I tried to get the main window by this, `[[NSApplication sharedApplication]mainWindow];` and then closing it. But was unsuccessful.

I dont think i have proper understanding yet with windows, views and controllers of cocoa. i am following **aaron hillegass's** ***COCOA Programming for Mac OS X*** book.
please suggest me some other tutorials so that i can understand this thing clearly.

Comment: Dint get your question.

Comment: when i create cocoa app, it already comes with a window,menu functions in the MainMenu.xib file, i need to load either that window or another custom window based on some condition. not both.

Comment: so when you are building, you are getting both the windows?

Comment: the default window launches everytime and it has a button with an action, which loads the custom window. but i need to do that without a button and not launch the main window.

Comment: So basically you want not to launch the main window. Also you want to open 2nd window from menu click. Am I right?

Comment: no, lets say i have a boolean. if it is 1, i would load default window, which comes in mainmenu.xib. if 0, i would load custom window, without any button interaction. i couldn't do it that way, thats why currently i have done it with the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to un-check the windows "Visible at Launch"

Then based on your BOOL value, you need to show the window and make it orderFront.

[image]